# The effect of doubling the sample rate in Spectrogram

Tags: stft

If we have an audio file and we only change the sample rate (double it), what changes our spectrogram will have (after using the stft)?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what exactly you mean by "doubling the sample rate". If you just change the number, than the spectrogram will look exactly the same, only the values on the X-axis will double as well.

If you actually up-sample by a factor of two, the spectrogram will have twice the frequency range. The lower half will be the same (more or less) than the original spectrum and the upper half will be zero (more or less).

The "more or less" part depends on the quality of your up-sampler.